# How can I do this query in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

is it possible and how this querie in a flask with SQLALchemy

```
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE status = 'SCHEDULE'
OR status = 'RECORDING'
OR status = 'FAILED'
AND fail_type='S3_CONNECTION'
```

I am using the following code:

```
Record().query.filter(
    Record.id == record_id,
    Record.status in (Status.SCHEDULED, Status.RECORDING)
    Record.status == Status.FAILED
    Record.fail_type == 'S3_CONNETION'
).one()
```

But this is all AND instead or or and

How can I do that querie?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
Record().query.filter(
    Record.id == record_id,
    or_(Record.status in (Status.SCHEDULED, Status.RECORDING,)
    Record.status == Status.FAILED),
    Record.fail_type == 'S3_CONNETION'
).one()
```